# Why do I get database error when I log into my updated ee site?

Tags: php, database, expressionengine

I wondered if you could help.

I updated my local site to new ee 2.7 and that went swell. I pushed up my files to the server and I can get the /admin.php login page but when I press login i get this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'used' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `exp_security_hashes` SET `used` = 1 WHERE `used` = 0 AND `hash` = '04ec7161468a13c61c984f39f646a76073bdab56' AND `session_id` = 0 AND `date` > 1381249552

Filename: core/EE_Security.php

Line Number: 169
```

Has anyone ever come across this from updating the ee cms before?

Cheers

Comment: forget to upgrade the database alongside the code?

Comment: hmmmm, the database was not changed in my local version and that worked fine!!

Comment: If you push the query UPDATE `exp_security_hashes` SET `used` = 1 WHERE `used` = 0 AND `hash` = '04ec7161468a13c61c984f39f646a76073bdab56' AND `session_id` = 0 AND `date` > 1381249552
 in the mysql console...it gives the same error?

Comment: not too sure how to do this in the console

Comment: yes sorry I do. it gives me `Unknown column 'used' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to get it resolved?

Comment: Can you confirm that you did run the full EE upgrade process? It's not just replacing the files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> There’s a bug in the Referrers module in upd.referrer.php.
>
> Line 154 should be:
>
> 'referrers', instead of 'comments',
>
> the full path of the file is
>
> system/expressionengine/modules/referrer/upd.referrer.php